# Why do I get the "dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Python3" error when running jupyter notebook and how can i fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos-catalina, python-venv

I wanted to run Jupyter notebook by:
`Jupyter notebook`
But i got the error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Python3
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

The last command i ran when trying to install Poetry on my mac (OS: 10.15 catalina) was `/usr/bin/python3 -m venv --copies --without-pip venv && ./venv/bin/python3` found [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/install.python-poetry.org/issues/24).
I don't even understand what it modifies in my environment.
So how can i fix it ?
Thanks in advance

I tried few solutions like :
`sudo ln -sf /path/to/your/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3` or modifying .bash_profile unsuccessfully.